# VBA- Comparing two columns and inserting a new row either above or below depending on values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large spreadsheet of data which is misaligned. This sheet is designed to compare data from two separate sources based on which date they occurred. The readings are slightly different so over the course of all the rows there is a misalignment.

The dates are in column A for the first reading and column D for the second reading. if the date in A < D then I need to insert a new row below and then copy the contents of column D and E down into the new row (Column E has the output for the respective date). On the flip side if A > D then I need to insert a new row above and move data from A, B and C into the new row. The final case is if the dates are correctly matched then I need to format Column F to say "Yes" and turn green. This last part is fine, it is the sections with A < D and A > D that I am struggling with.

I have a feeling that I have used the `EntireRow.Insert Shift:= xlShiftDown`, but this seems to be creating issues as I am only on the 32-Bit version of Excel.

EDIT:
The VBA needs to move up all the data by one row depending on the condition, as the copying and pasting method is only half of the issue. This script will be used to align dates.
Here is a small sample of my Data and what the VBA needs to do.

***This is what the data looks like:***
[image: Screenshot of table, before]

***And here is what I want it to look like:***
[image: Screenshot of table, manual changes]

The second image I moved the data manually like this, if the date in (A,1) > (D,1), I inserted a new row, cut the values from (D:E,1) and pasted them into the D:E of the new row. I then selected all of the data below in col D and E and dragged it 1 cell up to align it. if A < D then I did the inverse.

(note hopefully the pictures come through, it says i am unable ot insert images so is just a link for now)

Edit V2:
Here is the PQ code which has been copied from Ron's answer and pasted into my PQ advanced editor. The problem is showing up that
`Expression.Error: A join operation cannot result in a table with duplicate column names ("Date 1"). Details: [Type]` My current headers in the data are exactly that which can be seen in the earlier screenshots so in theory it should be a straight copy and paste across. I suspect I have accidentally altered something in the code while changing the name of the table to reference. Code seen below:

```
let
//Read in the two tables
//Be sure to change names in Source lines to actual table names in your workbook
//add index column to TableA to enable replace dups with nulls
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    TableA  = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date 1", type date}, {"Value", type number}, {"Value 2 (Src 1)", type number}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(TableA, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    TableB  = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Date 2", type date}, {"Value 2 (Src 2)", type number}}),

//FullOuter Join the two tables
//Then sort by Index column to regain original order
    join = Table.Join(#"Added Index","Date 1",TableB,"Date 2", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(join,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),

//Generate column with previous Index row
//check if there are duplicates
// (this is a faster procedure than referring to previous row with a single index column)
    prevRow = fnprevRow(#"Sorted Rows","Index"),

//if prevRow=Index then flag for deletion
//then remove the Index column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(prevRow, "delete", each [Previous Row]=[Index]),
    remIndex = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Previous Row"}),

//Replace TableA entries with nulls where flagged as duplicate
    x = Table.FromRecords(
            Table.TransformRows(
                remIndex,
                (r)=>
                    Record.TransformFields(r,
                    {
                        {"Date 1", each if r[delete] = true then null else _},
                        {"Value", each if r[delete] = true then null else _},
                        {"Value 2 (Src 1)", each if r[delete] = true then null else _}

                    })
            ), Value.Type(remIndex)
    ),

//remove the "delete" column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(x,{"delete"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Here is the VBA script that I have written so far:

```
Sub TestingDates()
    Dim sourceCell As Range, targetCell As Range, formatCell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastOccRow As Long
    
    LastOccRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To LastOccRow
        Set sourceCell = Range("A" & i)
        Set targetCell = Range("D" & i)
        Set formatCell = Range("F" & i)
    
        If targetCell.Value > sourceCell.Value Then
        
            Range("D" & i, "E" & i).Copy
            targetCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            targetCell.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            targetCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            
        ElseIf targetCell.Value < sourceCell.Value Then
        
            Range("A" & i, "B" & i, "C" & i).Copy
            targetCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            targetCell.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
            targetCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

       'This section works fine
        ElseIf targetCell.Value = sourceCell.Value Then
            formatCell.Value = "Yes"
            formatCell.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
            formatCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 97, 0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just join the tables based on the date column? You can do this in VBA, Power Query or even worksheet formulas.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld I'm not sure that's quite what I need as there are different amounts of readings for each date and hence it wont combine quite as I would hope. Thanks for your comment though!

Comment: If you were to edit your question to include a sample of data and how you would like it transformed, that would clarify things.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have made the edits, hopefully that helps to clarify things!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Power Query solution that creates your Output table from your Input table as shown in your question.

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

The basic algorithm is to do a FullOuter join of the two tables, based on the date column; then detect and delete the duplicated row entries from Table 1

If your real data is not fully represented by your sample, some change may need to be made in the coding.

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in the two tables
//Be sure to change names in Source lines to actual table names in your workbook
//add index column to TableA to enable replace dups with nulls
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableA"]}[Content],
    TableA  = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date 1", type date}, {"Value", type number}, {"Value 2 (Src 1)", type number}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(TableA, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableB"]}[Content],
    TableB  = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{{"Date 2", type date}, {"Value 2 (Src 2)", type number}}),

//FullOuter Join the two tables
//Then sort by Index column to regain original order
    join = Table.Join(#"Added Index","Date 1",TableB,"Date 2", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(join,{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),

//Generate column with previous Index row
//check if there are duplicates
// (this is a faster procedure than referring to previous row with a single index column)
    prevRow = fnPrevRow(#"Sorted Rows","Index"),

//if prevRow=Index then flag for deletion
//then remove the Index column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(prevRow, "delete", each [Previous Row]=[Index]),
    remIndex = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index", "Previous Row"}),

//Replace TableA entries with nulls where flagged as duplicate
    x = Table.FromRecords(
            Table.TransformRows(
                remIndex,
                (r)=>
                    Record.TransformFields(r,
                    {
                        {"Date 1", each if r[delete] = true then null else _},
                        {"Value", each if r[delete] = true then null else _},
                        {"Value 2 (Src 1)", each if r[delete] = true then null else _}

                    })
            ), Value.Type(remIndex)
    ),

//remove the "delete" column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(x,{"delete"})

in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

**Source Data1**
[image]

**Source Data2**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

***Edit to add Custom Function***

- Create a new query from `Other Sources => Blank Query`
- Rename the query: `fnPrevRow`
- Open the Advanced Editor and replace the code you see with the M-Code below.

```
(MyTable as table, MyColumnName as text) =>
let
    Source = MyTable,
    ShiftedList = {null} &  List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(Source, MyColumnName),1),
    Custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & {ShiftedList},
    Custom2 = Table.FromColumns(Custom1, Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"Previous Row"})
in
    Custom2
```

Comment: Hi Ron, this looks really great thank you! I am having a slight issue getting it to work though, I have changed the headers to the ones actually in my data and im getting two errors. Firstly, `Expression.Error: The import fnprevRow matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?`  and scondly after I press go to error it says`Expression.Error: The name 'fnprevRow' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.` I feel like this is a really simple thing im missing... any thoughts?

Comment: @Engineer101 Sorry about that.  My fault.  `fnPrevRow` is a custom function that I forgot to include.  I'll edit my Answer to include that

Comment: That seems to have sorted it out, the custom function is now added and I think is working, Thank you! I'm now getting a warning saying that `Expression.Error: A join operation cannot result in a table with duplicate column names ("Date 1").` any thoughts why this may be?

Comment: @Engineer101 It means exactly what it says. An Excel (or PQ) table cannot have two columns with the same name.  Maybe when you "*changed the headers to the ones actually in my data*" something in that process caused the problem?  You could do a nested join, but, since the final result has date columns with two different names, probably easiest to just adjust the name of one of the date columns -- either in your data or in the query before the Join.

Comment: That makes sense... Slightly confusing though as the column names are both already different, unfortunately I cannot share the exact names or screenshots as that is not my data to share! I have also re-copied across the M code you had written and changed the headers on a copy of the sheet to be exactly the ones I gave as an example and still to no avail. This is where my lack of skills in PQ are starting to show!! is there anything else I may be missing? Thanks again for all your help

Comment: @Engineer101 I suspect that somewhere in the alterations you made in the code to accommodate the "real" table column headers you changed a reference incorrectly.  I suppose one work-around (assuming the same number of columns) would be to 1. Use the original code as provided.  2. After the Source, and Source2 steps, insert a step which renames the columns to the same as you showed in your examples. 3. At the last step, add a step which renames the columns back to what they should be.

Comment: That does sound plausible, I have hardly worked with PQ before so that is quite likely! I had a go using the original code and is still doing the same thing, I will edit my question to include the code which I have copied out of your response, changed the table name in accordance with the one created and hopefully that will help!

Comment: @Engineer101 In the PQ code you just pasted into your question, you are referring to the same table for Source and Source2 (`Table11`).  In your question you indicated the two tables were different.

Comment: My apologies for not having made that clear! The formatting was a little off as I had written a separate macro to pull data from 2 different spreadsheets into one master sheet. That master sheet contains the data which needs to be aligned by date as mentioned. the formatting is a little out of whack with the screenshots I had included, hence why it looks like 2 separate tables. My apologies! Would it be possible to skip the macro stage and use the PQ to do all the steps in one? i.e combine the two source spreadsheets and align by date?

Comment: @Engineer101 that is how the query works. It assumes two different tables. Just use source to refer to the first table and source2 to the second table. No VBA macro required.

Comment: That's worked perfectly, I just references the two original sheets and it has pulled together into one just as needed, thank you so much!! I really appreciate all your time on helping me solve this issue. I will mark the answer as accepted now :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but i think coping and inserting a row pasts the copied stuff in the inserted row. This could have lead to problems. I changed a few things, hopefully it suits your issue.

```
Sub TestingDates()
Dim sourceCell As Range, targetCell As Range, formatCell As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim LastOccRow As Long

LastOccRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastOccRow
    Set sourceCell = Range("A" & i)
    Set targetCell = Range("D" & i)
    Set formatCell = Range("F" & i)

    If targetCell.Value > sourceCell.Value Then
        
        Cells.Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range("D" & i, "E" & i).Copy Range("D" & i + 1)
        'Range("D" & i, "E" & i).Cut Range("D" & i + 1)
        i = i + 1
        
    ElseIf targetCell.Value < sourceCell.Value Then
        
        Cells.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Range("A" & i + 1, "C" & i + 1).Copy Range("A" & i)
        'Range("A" & i + 1, "C" & i + 1).Cut Range("A" & i)
        i = i + 1

   'This section works fine
    ElseIf targetCell.Value = sourceCell.Value Then
        formatCell.Value = "Yes"
        formatCell.Interior.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)
        formatCell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 97, 0)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Max, Thank you for the answer! unfortunately it doesn't seem to have fully sorted the issue. It has prevented excel crashing every time I try to run it though which is good news! The data still wont line up in date order as needed, does anyone else have any suggestions on how to make this work?